# schedule alarm on device from web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am creating a web app using Reactjs and Firebase and I need to schedule an alarm on the device from the web app. Are there any plugins available for this ?

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this NPM package which will show you a message at the desired time

**URL** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert

**DEMO** - https://codesandbox.io/s/l2mo430lzq

Alternative There are probably multiple ways to do this:

1. Check current time in componentDidMount
2. Use setTimeout to set up a function to change the visibility of the button when needed again.

Comment: The package you suggested doesn't allow you to specify the time of the notification; and for the second alternative it's not possible because the alarm should work even when the app is not running !

Comment: @shymaa - The easiest way to achieve this is the alternative option which I have mentioned. You just have to keep updating the timer at every second and when you hit the desired value you can proceed to take further actions.

Comment: But this alternative won't work if the app is not running right ?

Comment: Yes it won’t if app is not running.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue ! I need to set the alarm and make it work even if the app is not running !